# Command works on command line, but fails in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, glassfish

When trying to setup Glassfish configuration in a batch file there is one command that works when run directly from the command line - but fails when put in a windows batch file.

The command:

```
call asadmin.bat create-auth-realm --classname com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm --property jaas-context="ldapRealm":directory="ldap\://domain.com\:389:base-dn=dc\=domain,dc\=com:group-base-dn=ou\=Groups,ou\=domain,dc\=com":search-bind-dn="CN\=username,OU\=Accounts,OU\=domain,DC\=com":search-bind-password="password":search-filter="(&(objectCategory\=user)(sAMAccountName\=%s))":group-search-filter="(&(objectCategory\=group)(member\=%d))" a-realm
```

When run on the command line exactly as above it completes with the response:

```
Command create-auth-realm executed successfully.
```

When run from a batch file exactly as above it fails with the response:

```
(member\ was unexpected at this time.
```

Note that the escaping of some equals characters is for Glassfish, not an attempt at escaping characters for the windows batch command.

My guess is that when run in a batch file, the batch file is treating some characters as special. I have tried escaping the parentheses with no luck.

How can this command work in a batch file!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in the variables %s and %d.

If they need to be interpreted by the batch file (they are environment variables), they should be %s% and %d%.

IF they are not environment variables, and need to be interpreted in (don't know what glassfish is), then they should be %%d and %%s

Comment: This answer is 99% correct.
There is a slight curve ball in this one though, I had to actually escape the % character twice. e.g. %%%%d and %%%%s. Don't really know why.

Comment: It is an assumption (as said, i don't know glassfish), but probably, once your command is interpreted in your batch file, and % is passed to asadmin.bat or to glassfish, it can not be interpreted again.

Comment: the `call` command adds another layer of parsing, so the first parsing reduces `%%%%` to `%%`. That leaves the second layer to  reduce `%%` to `%`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a problem with the percent signs.
In a batch file percent signs are removed, when no matching percent sign is found or a enclosed *variable* isn't defined.
On the command line they simply stay unchanged.

In a batch file a percent sign can be escaped by a second percent.

`call asadmin.bat create-auth-realm --classname com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm --property jaas-context="ldapRealm":directory="ldap\://domain.com\:389:base-dn=dc\=domain,dc\=com:group-base-dn=ou\=Groups,ou\=domain,dc\=com":search-bind-dn="CN\=username,OU\=Accounts,OU\=domain,DC\=com":search-bind-password="password":search-filter="(&(objectCategory\=user)(sAMAccountName\=%%s))":group-search-filter="(&(objectCategory\=group)(member\=%%d))" a-realm`

Answer (score 0):

Windows use of carets ( ^ ) to escape special characters. Try to replace the backslashes at the carets.

Comment: A thousand apologies. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
call asadmin.bat create-auth-realm --classname com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm --property jaas-context="ldapRealm":directory="ldap\://domain.com\:389:base-dn=dc\=domain,dc\=com:group-base-dn=ou\=Groups,ou\=domain,dc\=com":search-bind-dn="CN\=username,OU\=Accounts,OU\=domain,DC\=com":search-bind-password="password":search-filter="(&(objectCategory\=user)(sAMAccountName\=%s))":group-search-filter="(&(objectCategory\=group)(member\=%d))" a-realm
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ^
```

the &'s need to be escaped with ^ I think. try it... `;)`